# How to graph events on a timeline

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I tracked all the movies I watched in 2019 and I want to represent the year on a graph using matplotlib, pyplot or seaborn. I saw a graph by a user who also tracked the movies he watched in a year:
I want a graph like this:
[image]

How do I represent each movie as an 'event' on a timeline?

For reference, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlF0q.png) is a look at my table.

(sorry if basic)

Comment: Have a go first, tell us what you've tried and work from there. `matplotlib` or `seaborn` would both be useful for this; you can also plot directly from `pandas` objects.

Comment: I now know I need to convert the date format from 2019-01-01 to just 2019-01 etc. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I've made an assumption (from your comment) that your `date` column is type `str`. Here is code that will produce the graph:

#### Modify your `pd.DataFrame` object

Firstly, a function to add a column to your dataframe:

```
def modify_dataframe(df):
    """ Modify dataframe to include new columns """
    df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.month
    return df
```

The `pd.to_datetime` function converts the series `df['Date']` to a datetime series; and I'm creating a new column called `Month` which equates to the month number.

From this column, we can generate `X` and `Y` coordinates for your plot.

```
def get_x_y(df):
    """ Get X and Y coordinates; return tuple """
    series = df['Month'].value_counts().sort_index()
    new_series = series.reindex(range(1,13)).fillna(0).astype(int)
    return new_series.index, new_series.values
```

This takes in your modified dataframe, creates a series that counts the number of occurrences of each month. Then if there are any missing months, `fillna` fills them in with a value of `0`. Now you can begin to plot.

#### Plotting the graph

I've created a plot that looks like the desired output you linked.

Firstly, call your functions:

```
df = modify_dataframe(df)
X, Y = get_x_y(df)
```

Create the canvas and axis to plot on to.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, title='Films watched per month - 2019')
```

Generate x-labels. This will replace the current month `int` values (i.e. 1, 2, 3...) on the x-axis.

```
xlabels = [datetime.datetime(2019, i, 1).strftime("%B") for i in list(range(1,13))]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=45, ha='right')
```

Set the x-ticks, and x-label.

```
ax.set_xticks(range(1,13))
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
```

Set the y-axis, y-lim, and y-label.

```
ax.set_yticks(range(0, max(s1.values)+2))
ax.set_ylim(0, max(s1.values)+1)
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
```

To get your desired output, fill underneath the graph with a block-colour (I've chosen green here but you can change it to something else).

```
ax.fill_between(X, [0]*len(X), Y, facecolor='green')
ax.plot(X, Y, color="black", linewidth=3, marker="o")
```

Plot your graph!

```
plt.show()  # or plt.savefig('output.png', format='png')
```

[image: Plot of films]

Comment: Thanks for your help! However when i execute the portion : "df = modify_dataframe(df)"  an error is returned. It says: "day is out of range for month"

Comment: This might be because `pd.to_datetime` is inferring the date format incorrectly - I've updated the answer to use the `format` parameter. - Please try again!